# Accessing properties from an object directly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance

In Javascript, if we have a scenario in which there is a large object and we need to access its properties then which approach is better?

Suppose we have this object:

```
let largeObj = {
  items: {
    item: [
      {
        id: "0001",
        type: "donut",
        name: "Cake",
        ppu: 0.55,
        batters: {
          batter: [
            {
              id: "1001",
              type: "Regular"
            },
            {
              id: "1002",
              type: "Chocolate"
            },
            {
              id: "1003",
              type: "Blueberry"
            },
            {
              id: "1004",
              type: "Devil's Food"
            }
          ]
        },
        topping: [
          {
            id: "5001",
            type: "None"
          },
          {
            id: "5002",
            type: "Glazed"
          },
          {
            id: "5005",
            type: "Sugar"
          },
          {
            id: "5007",
            type: "Powdered Sugar"
          },
          {
            id: "5006",
            type: "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
          },
          {
            id: "5003",
            type: "Chocolate"
          },
          {
            id: "5004",
            type: "Maple"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and we want to create `firstBatterAndTopping` object which has first batter and first topping data. Now, if we access properties of this object in below three ways, which approach is better in terms of performance. Is there any difference in these or these will perform the same. Or is there any other scenario like this in which this will impact performance?

```
let firstBatterAndTopping = {
    batterId: largeObj.items.item[0].batters.batter[0].id,
    batterType: largeObj.items.item[0].batters.batter[0].type,
    toppingId: largeObj.items.item[0].topping[0].id,
    toppingType: largeObj.items.item[0].topping[0].type
}
```

or

```
let firstItem = largeObj.items.item[0];
let firstBatterAndTopping = {
    batterId: firstItem.batters.batter[0].id,
    batterType: firstItem.batters.batter[0].type,
    toppingId: firstItem.topping[0].id,
    toppingType: firstItem.topping[0].type
}
```

or

```
let firstItem = largeObj.items.item[0];
let firstBatter = firstItem.batters.batter[0];
let firstTopping = firstItem.topping[0]
let firstBatterAndTopping = {
    batterId: firstBatter.id,
    batterType: firstBatter.type,
    toppingId: firstTopping.id,
    toppingType: firstTopping.type
}
```

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-1fu32b?file=script.js)

Comment: You should write the code in the way that makes it easiest to understand and maintain. The performance differences in your example code are absolutely negligible.

Comment: @jsejcksn yes, you are right. But still I need to know which is better one even if differences are negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Try [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) out! Is a javascript library very useful for managing complex objects with a lot of nests.
Following a simple scenario:

```
import produce from "immer"

const baseState = [
    {
        title: "Learn TypeScript",
        done: true
    },
    {
        title: "Try Immer",
        done: false
    }
]

const nextState = produce(baseState, draftState => {
    draftState.push({title: "Tweet about it"})
    draftState[1].done = true
})
// the new item is only added to the next state,
// base state is unmodified
expect(baseState.length).toBe(2)
expect(nextState.length).toBe(3)

// same for the changed 'done' prop
expect(baseState[1].done).toBe(false)
expect(nextState[1].done).toBe(true)

// unchanged data is structurally shared
expect(nextState[0]).toBe(baseState[0])
// ...but changed data isn't.
expect(nextState[1]).not.toBe(baseState[1])
```